# How to use UTF-8 with Firebird and PHP Data Objects (PDO)

Tags: php, pdo, firebird

With `mysql` I can just do this to solve the problem:

```
$diveOptions = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"); // set names utf-8 and works well
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql.example.com;dbname=example_db',"username","password",diveOptions);
```

But I can't do the same with the firebird's pdo connection.

How can I solve this problem of `UTF-8`?

Already tried `charset=utf8` in pdo configuration don t work too..

```
$str_conn = "firebird:dbname=C:\db\banco.gdb;charset=utf8;host=localhost";
$dbh = new PDO($str_conn, "SYSDBA", "masterkey");
```

In my db was set to nome like this:

```
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET NONE COLLATION NONE;
```

Comment: I don't know PDO nor PHP, but you will need to set the connection encoding to UTF8. Most drivers expects the Firebird character set name, so it should be UTF8 without a dash. According to [this](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.connection.php) the property name is `charset`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel set in the parameter like in this example above?

Comment: Yes, secondary source: http://mapopa.blogspot.nl/2009/04/php5-and-firebird-pdo-on-ubuntu-hardy.html However, this will only work if the columns in the database currently have a character set other than `NONE`; better yet: it should be `UTF8`. Otherwise no character set conversion is done.